# Filter the objects that have the same field value of the value that we provide

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

My goal is to show only banners that have the same CODE provided in the KEYS array to filter. So I only want the banners which have the same code contained in the array KEYS. Thanks for the help.

```js
const keys = ['343747', '213747', '123444']
export const banners = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Cashback',
    code: '343747',
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Cosmetic',
    code: '213747',
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jeans',
    code: '123444',
    },
    {
    id: 4,
    name: 'WelcomeBonus',
    code: '54344',
    },
]
```

Number 4 has a code that is not present in the KEYS array so it shouldn't be shown.

I tried to use the FILTER, REDUCE or MAP method but I couldn't get to the solution. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `const filteredBanners = banners.filter((banner) => keys.includes(banner.code))`

`filter` will return an array of values from the original array that satisfies the given function.

Comment: Thanks everything worked perfectly. I'm really grateful